# Is there a term for whether the middle of an uppercase M touches the baseline?

Tags: typography, terminology

A number of fonts (Gotham, Vera, Nexa) have an uppercase M where the middle V shape doesn't touch the baseline. In many (most?) other fonts, that shape does touch the baseline. Is there a formal or informal term for this difference (à la "two story a")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call the V shape in a letter M the "vertex".

On [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/differences?first=Sackers+Open+Antique+Roman&second=Imprint+MT+Shadow) they use this terminology, and call the V shape in the M a "centre vertex".

They describe it like this

[image]

The upward pointing corners of the M are sometimes called an "apex", so technically, the M only has one vertex, so there's no need to call it a "centre vertex".  You could just say "the vertex is above the baseline" to describe it.

Comment: I was going to post the exact same content, but I took too long browsing through Identifont before this question popped up ^^'

Comment: While the apex is the highest point, a vertex is simply a corner. There are three vertices in M, so there *is* a need to specify which vertex you're talking about -- even though only one is actually capable of touching the baseline. You certainly couldn't talk about "the vertex".

Comment: Not so sure about that @AndrewLeach -  there's a [glossary here on fontsmith.com](https://www.fontsmith.com/blog/2016/06/29/the-a-z-of-typographic-terms) which specifically says the vertex is "The point where two strokes meet at the bottom of a character".

Comment: I offer you [a differing definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vertex) (see sense 2). Also, if you're designing a font, then the geometry definition becomes important.

Comment: @AndrewLeach in normal English, I would agree a vertex is any corner. But typography uses some technical terms in different ways from normal English usage. This might be an example of that. - other examples are "foot", "flag", "ear", etc. Some aren't even English, "Halbfett" for example.